# Magento SOAP v1 API adds a 2nd broken image after successfully adding a real image

Tags: magento-1.7, api

I am adding a new Product using the API, I am then running the function below to add an Image to the newly created product.

The problem is, when I view the newly created product, it has 1 valid image that was uploaded and then 1 broken image.  It seems like it always makes 2 image records in the Admin panel even though only 1 image is uploaded.

I have tested this on multiple Magento installs and the problem persist everywhere.  I am at a lost as to what to do next.

View this image to see the result after adding 1 image through the API, you can see it makes 2 entries (1 good one and 1 bad one)...

[image]

You can see in the image that the broken image is selected as the default.  I cannot figure out why this broken image is even being created instead of my uploaded image being used.

Below is the Image API code I am using.

```
function uploadImage( $sku, $imagePath, $productId ) {
    global $proxy;
    global $sessionId;

    $sku = strtoupper($sku );
    $newImage = array(
        'file' => array(
            'name' => 'file_name',
            'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath)),
            'mime'    => 'image/png'
        ),
        'label'    => "Item:" . $sku,
        'position' => 0,
        'types'    => array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail', 'ebayimage' ),
        'exclude'  => 0
    );
    try {
        $imageFilename = $proxy->call(
            $sessionId,
            'catalog_product_attribute_media.create',
            array(
                $productId,
                $newImage
            )
        );
        echo '<br>Image Filename Added '.$imageFilename;
        //var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.list', $sku));
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        print( "Error assigning image to $sku: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n" );
    }
}
```

And here is my Product creating code which then calls the Image function above...

```
try {
    // Create new product
    $productId = $proxy->call(
        $sessionId,
        'product.create',
        array(
            'simple',
            $attributeSet,
            $productSku,
            $productData
        )
    );
    echo 'Product ID Create: '.$productId;

    // Upload and attach Image
    $imagePath = 'twitter-header.png';
    uploadImage( $productSku, $imagePath, $productId );

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "Product creation error $e";
}
```

Any ideas why it would be creating this dummy broken image record everytime it creates a valid record?

**UPDATE**
I was starting to think that possibly another extension on the magento site I am working on might be the cause but I have now tried my code on a brand new fresh Magento Install and the issue still exist.  For every Image that I create through the API, it then creates an additional broken image with the original image name with `_1` added to the end of the filename.

I cannot figure out why this is happening, surely such a huuuuuge bug wouldn't have lived in Magento this long?

Here is the result of the API call...You can see 2 image records for each Image added.  The 2nd is the broken image and it is assigned the thumbnail, small_image, and image values

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. What did you do to fix?

Comment: @eleven11 I never was able to find a solution, if you do please share it as an answer to this question and i'll select your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start in the API call itself, it looks to be a pretty hefty method, with lots of things going on:

- https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/6ea22c9abff24da3f3f2aaed59c527ff803c02eb/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php#L107

A quick glance at the code, it may be permissions related, since some temporary files are created in the `create` method.

I would start by dumping or logging the `$data` just to see if its showing twice from your one call.

Hope this helps.